# Access cookies || localSorage from content script - Chrome extension

Tags: scripting, cookies, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

Is there any way to access ***cookies*** || ***localSorage*** from **content script**?

for example i have **localStorage.shBox='true'**

and I want to access this from **content script**.. how can I make this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to access extension's localStorage you need to send a request to your background page:

In script.js:

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest("getStorageData", function(response) {
    console.log("response:", response);
}
```

In background.html:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request === "getStorageData") {
        sendResponse(localStorage["data"]);
    }
});
```

Cookies API is described in details [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/cookies.html).